# How to display string in html format on jsf page

Tags: string, jsf-2, string-formatting

I m using jsf2.0. And i m making one email application, I m calling web service to read the content of the file, and i m using SAX parser to extract the content from the  to read the file. And i m storing that content in string variable and set it in setter method. And displaying it in outputLabel. Now, problem is when the content is displayed in jsf page at that time it is not displaying in proper format. it's displayed in one line. But when i see the view source of page at that time in view source it's displayed in proper format. So,what should be the solution. Please reply me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out if `h:outputText`'s `escape` flag set to `false` can help you.

> escape: This attribute sets a boolean flag value that determines if
>   sensitive HTML and XML characters should be escaped in the output
>   generated by the component. It's default value is "true".

(Description from [here](http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/outputText.shtml))

Answer (score 2):

Set the CSS `white-space` property of the parent element to `pre`.

E.g.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.xml}" styleClass="preformatted" />
```

with

```css
.preformatted {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the good old html `<pre>...</pre>` around your text will display the text as you like it (assuming that it is a plain text without markup).